# Find out what App stores in Cache

Tags: android

my Android app seems to use too much cache space. The apk is less than 2 MB, but the App uses about 5 MB of cache. Now I want to find out what could use that much space.
Maybe it's the background image, which is a 700 KB Jpg (it is a photo)?

I don't store any data explicitly in the cache, so I wonder where these 5 MB come from.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check the Heap and Allocation Tracker of your application on DDMS
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html